# Exercises in comparison geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning

After taking an introductory graduate differential geometry course last year and doing a bit of reading about the Ricci flow, I was considering reading Cheeger and Ebin's book on comparison geometry to get some exposure to classical results in Riemannian geometry.

However, the book doesn't really have any exercises. Is there by any chance a nice bank of exercises in Riemannian/comparison geometry (say, from a course that uses the book) with which it would be good to follow along?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* has a few chapters on comparison geometry with quite a few exercises, so it might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, ill check it out!